# Ionic: NgMap not displayed on android device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Am using  NgMap in an ionic project.
This is my HTML file code:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home page">
<ion-content>
<ng-map zoom="11" min-zoom="7" max-zoom="14" center="current-position" data-tap-disabled="true">
<marker position="current-position" icon="{url:'img/map-marker-13.png',
scaledSize:[50,50]}">
</marker>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When i run my project on android 4.4.2 device , the map is not displayed.
Any help please.

Comment: Did you inject the ngMap in your module?, can you provide maybe some logs? maybe it will help

Comment: Yes i injected it .Could  you tell me  how can i procide  log when running on device ?

Comment: by adding -lc when building to your device

Comment: my problem is resolved , by adding cache-view="false"   to the view that contains the map

Comment: Good to know thanks for the info